# Optimizing of winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, optimization

I have a program that loads a tab that has roughly 332 text boxes it loads. When loading a new tab there is a 2-3 second delay before the tab can be displayed. I have tried to suspend and resume and even looked into threading but found out that a winform can only use one thread.

I was wondering if there was a way to create the text boxes in another thread and then add them into the main form or a way to better create 332 text boxes.

thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure why you have that many text boxes? What you can do is not uses text boxes but rather do your own text painting by trapping the WM_PAINT message.

Comment: wrap multiple textboxes into logical group-box controls if you can ?

Comment: The program is used to keep track of multiple RPG characters. The text boxes have to match a location on a bit map background. source can be found https://github.com/darkwisperer/Dungeon-Master-Sheet

Comment: There is something called DoubleBuffering in winforms try setting it to true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your layout, I'd strongly recommend replacing the textboxes with a DataGridView, or otherwise loading the textboxes on scroll with some kind of continous-control .
The main bottle neck is the creation of handles. In winforms, each control gets its own handle (even labels), and when used in large numbers such as this, can indeed give performance problems.

If a datagridview is not an option, can you give some more information on the layout (a screenshot perhaps?), so the community can have a go at alternatives. Creating the textboxes in another thread will create problems when you try to add them, but you could create them only when needed.

Comment: thanks for your quick response and thorough answer. I will try the dattagrid.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: don't use 300 text boxes. You can only use *one* text box at a time. The rest of the data you can just draw, and when the user wants to edit it you create the edit control for it. This is exactly how a grid works, so I recommend using a grid or similar control.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, and it goes further to affect initialisation code for controls on tabs that has not get activated before.

My workaround is to block the program with a "loading..." splash and programatically click the tabs so that the controls get loaded/activated. Once this is done, the tabpage shoud not take as long to display again.

Although I agree with others in that you may want to look into reducing the number of controls in a single tab.